# Trying to have link shown if user owns post or if user is staff

Tags: django

I'm trying to hide an Edit and Delete button from posts made unless it's the user who made it, or the user is staff/superuser. I got it to work in my `views.py` to allow staff users to edit, but I can't get it to show in the html.

`{% if request.user == room.host and room.host.is_staff %}`

This is what I have currently but it's not showing me the links as a staff user.

Comment: Use `or` instead of `and` in your `{% if %}` tag

Comment: @EzonZhao That didn't change a thing, the links still aren't there for me to click

Comment: Excuse me, but according to your description, the second condition should be `request.user.is_staff`. `{% if request.user == room.host or request.user.is_staff %}`

Comment: @EzonZhao I did find a successful answer on a thread from 2013, simply `user.is_staff` works, but so does `request.user.is_staff`. Thank you!